# segue fired by NSTimer

Tags: ios, nstimer, segue

im pretty new to the iOS thing and I think this should be easy to answer:
I have a Master-Detail-Application with many subviews which works fine and in the background I have several timers running. Now when a timer fires I want to switch to a single view from wherever the user is at the moment. (with a button to go back where he came from)

what is the best way to do this?

should I somehow get the current active viewcontroller and tell him to do the segue?

thanks!

**Update:**
for clarification: I have a non UI related (NSObject) Scheduler for all my timers which somehow has to notify my UI when a timer fires to popup a special View, which should overlay the current active view and show it again when dismissed.
a regular fullscreen popup.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to do a segue when a timer fires, that's easy. Do

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0 target:self selector:@selector(segue) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

-(void)segue {
  [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"id" sender:self];
}
```

Comment: can i somehow create a segue without an origin as i don't know which view is active (i don't have an identifier). additionally my timers get handeled in a not gui related class, so i somehow have to get the active viewcontroller to tell him to segue?